# Triggering drag event from iframe to parent with touch

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, touch, jquery-ui-draggable

Issue: Mouse movements are not always being sensed on touch.

I am currently using jQuery UI drag and jQuery Touch Punch to convert touch events into mouse events. Everything works fine on desktop browsers.

I can get it to execute the draggable 'start' function, but it doesn't always start the draggable 'drag' function. I have listeners set up everywhere to see what is going on and it doesn't show any mouse movements after the start function has run - both in the window and in the parent document. Scrolling, then turns on (which is usually prevented by preventDefault();). I have to remove my finger and place it back down to continue the drag. However, if I place certain e.preventDefault()s I can get the drag to operate fine (in other words, start on the intial swipe) by the third or fourth time of initiating the draggable.

Here is a condensed version:

```
$(window).mousedown(function(e){
  drag(e);
});

function drag(e){
  $iframefix.show();
  $draggable.draggable({
     start: function(e, ui){
            // this function runs well, but at the end of it, I don't seem to register
            // any mouse movements in the document or window as I move my finger 
            // around, and even using .trigger('mousemove') does not register an event.
     },
     drag: function(e, ui){

     }
  });
  $draggable.trigger(e); 
}
```

My guess are that it has to do with the fact that the mouse event originates in the iframe, and when .trigger() is used, perhaps jQuery normalizes the event so it is looking back into the window (e.originalEvent). Maybe this is confusing jQuery touch punch from sensing the mouse movement (maybe it thinks it is a click instead).

Here is jQuery Touch Punch - it is a small script that wraps around the jQuery mouse events:

https://raw.github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/master/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js

Alternatively, perhaps this is the use of e.preventDefault() or e.stopPropagation or return false in an area I'm not looking.

Regardless, something is stopping it from sensing my finger from moving around after dragstart.

Comment: Try adding a `return false;` in your `mousedown` handler above. Maybe the default action is causing the inconsistency.

Comment: Great suggestion. But unfortunately it didn't work the magic. I've tried alot of preventDefault()s and stopPropagation()s as well, under many different mouse events. However that doesn't mean that the answer won't lie with these in certain strategic areas, I just haven't found one yet. Thanks

Comment: Did you ever solve this?